# Find documents including email addresses in SharePoint 365 Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I am trying to search my document libraries to find documents that include any personal identifiers.

How can I run a search from the UI (e.g. context search) to find documents including emails?

If this is not possible can I do it in PowerShell?

Thanks

Comment: Just a warning, if the email is in an image based PDF or another image format currently not supported for indexing by search, then you will not be able to find them

Answer (score 0):

This overview cover the subject pretty well, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/search-for-and-find-personal-data

Comment: Kasper, email is not included in the SensitiveType catalogue. I'm looking for KQL or if not then PowerShell commands

Comment: True, you will have to add the pattern for email yourself . In SharePoint online the KQL does not support pattern matching so that is, as far as I recall it, not an option

Comment: Perhaps this will be use full, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/customize-or-create-a-new-sensitive-information-type